# Avoiding repeating the same line Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file that always contains the host name at the top line of the file followed by the capacity required:

```
HOST1
10g
1g
2g
```

From the file I need to extract the `HOST` line to make up the text line I want to create as well as the capacity line sequentially line by line. It also numbers the lines `001` onwards dependent on how many lines.

I want to get several lines like this:

```
The capacity of HOST1 is 001 10g
The capacity of HOST1 is 002 1g
The capacity of HOST1 is 003 2g
etc etc
```

I've tried to do this using a `foreach` condition below and also searched on here how do so but its a pretty bespoke problem to describe :(

```
$file = Get-Content $filename | Select-Object -skip 1 

foreach ($line in $file)
{
$count = $count +1
$FileCount = "{0:D3}" -f $count 
Write-Host "The capacity of $HostName is $FileCount $file
}
```

It creates this though;

```
The capacity of HOST1 is 001 10g 1g 2g

The capacity of HOST1 is 002 10g 1g 2g

The capacity of HOST1 is 003 10g 1g 2g
```

I'm very new to Powershell and have tried several places to find the solution to this. Apologies upfront for noob content!

Comment: Can you show some lines of your "source" file as well?

Comment: Use `$line`, not `$file` inside loop.

Comment: My Source file is displayed as the top of the post, HOST1 first line, 2g second line, 3g third line etc

Comment: Wow PetSerAl thank you, just changed to $line not $file. That's taken me around 2 weeks of playing around with various while true, foreach etc to not even think i'd got something so simple so wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$file = get-content $filename

$count = 0
$Hostname = $file[0]
foreach ($line in $file[1..$($file.Length-1)]) {
    $count = $count +1
    $FileCount = "{0:D3}" -f $count 
    Write-Host "The capacity of $HostName is $FileCount $line"
}
```

One-liner which can be used in `ForEach` (credits to LotPings) - if you're not sure why use `++$Count` instead of `$Count++` check [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/08/pre-and-post-incrementing-do-while-loop-in-powershell/) (credits to JamesC. for the link):

```
"The capacity of {0} is {1:D3} {2}" -f $Hostname,++$Count,$line
```

Output:

> The capacity of HOST1 is 001 10g
>
> The capacity of HOST1 is 002 1g
>
> The capacity of HOST1 is 003 2g

### Explanation:

In general what you did was very close if only you changed `$file` to `$line` as pointed out by PetSerAl. Some more suggestion could be to avoid importing file twice (not visible in your code but you obviously had to import first line of the file to `$HostName`. You can do it by saving `$file[0]` to `$HostName` and then iterating all but first element.

Comment: Thank you so much certainly way slicker and points me to further learning areas.

Comment: Ok I will have a look in to arrays because at the top of my code I had:

       $file = "h:\My Documents\Powershell_Work\Temp\volumes.txt"
       $Host = Get-Content $file | Select-Object -first 1
       $LineCount = Get-Content $file |Measure-Object -Line

Comment: You could reduce the ForEach content to one line `"The capacity of {0} is {1:D3} {2}" -f $Hostname,++$Count,$line`

Comment: @LotPings - added, thanks. I included both versions as your is more elegant and mine might be easier to read for less experienced scriptwriters.

Comment: Agreed, well this is a good example to explain the difference between `++$Count` and `$Count++` - did happen to me also

Comment: Useful ScriptingGuy blog on [pre and post-incrementing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/08/pre-and-post-incrementing-do-while-loop-in-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks @JamesC. - added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Other method:

```
$N=-1
get-content $filename  | %{ if($N++ -eq -1) {$HST=$_} else {"The capacity of {0} is {1:D3} {2}" -f $HST, $N, $_}}
```

Comment: Appreciate the solutions and i've started to incorporate % instead of foreach, good learning day from this first post.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, this is a problem that lends itself to using the `switch` statement quite well:

```
$count = 1
switch -regex -file $filename 
{
    ^HOST {
        $hostName = $_
        continue
    }
    default {
        "The capacity of $hostName is {0:D3} $_" -f $count++
        continue
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that PowerShell's `switch` is actually a loop. The `-File` option tells it to loop over each line in the file. A regex matches "HOST" and the associated action captures the hostname to use in subsequent messages.

Comment: This is more like ksh that i'm used to so I will look at using this style too as its more familiar.